# WooCommerce "Related Products for WooCommerce" plug-in display order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I am using "[Related Products for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wt-woocommerce-related-products/)" plug-in 1.4.6 by [WebToffee](https://www.webtoffee.com) to display related products in each product page of an eCommerce website.
I am trying to display related products in the same order as they were entered for each product (a very specific order for each product) but to no avail. I have tried every sorting option of the plug-in.

Does anyone know how to achieve that with some additional PHP ?
For instance, for upsells, I am using the following code in the functions.php file of the theme, which works as expected :

```
// ORDER BY
add_filter( 'woocommerce_upsells_orderby', 'filter_woocommerce_upsells_orderby', 10, 1 );
function filter_woocommerce_upsells_orderby( $orderby ){
    return "none";
};

// ORDER
add_filter( 'woocommerce_upsells_order', 'filter_woocommerce_upsells_order', 10, 1 );
function filter_woocommerce_upsells_order($order){
    return 'menu_order'; 
};
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this helps.

```
// ORDER BY
add_filter( 'wt_related_products_orderby', 'filter_woocommerce_wt_related_orderby', 10, 1 );
function filter_woocommerce_wt_related_orderby( $orderby ){
    return "none";
}

add_filter( 'wt_related_products_order', 'filter_woocommerce_wt_related_order', 10, 1 );
function filter_woocommerce_wt_related_order($order){
    return 'menu_order'; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the solution.
It is a hack of the file "related.php" located in
wp-content/plugins/wt-woocommerce-related-products/woocommerce/single-product

This php uses the WP_Query() function with an array "$args".
By default, the $args array looks as follows :

```
array(5) { ["post_type"]=> string(7) "product" ["posts_per_page"]=> string(2) "20" ["orderby"]=> string(4) "rand" ["order"]=> string(3) "ASC" ["post__in"]=> array(14) { [10]=> int(12925) [5]=> int(13049) [12]=> int(13081) [4]=> int(12568) [1]=> int(12991) [13]=> int(12328) [3]=> int(12566) [2]=> int(12999) [9]=> int(13085) [8]=> int(12589) [11]=> int(13047) [6]=> int(12570) [7]=> int(12619) [0]=> int(12695) } }
```

The trick is to make sure that the list of IDs in the "post__in" array are in the right order, and then to "force" "orderby" and "order" to the right values.

- step 1 : insert `$copy = $related;` at line 285 so that the IDs don't get scrambled
- step 2 : disable `'orderby' => $orderby,` and `'order' => $order,` at lines 300 & 301
- step 3 : insert `$args['orderby'] = 'post__in';$args['order'] = 'ASC';` at line 532

Finally, $args array looks like that :

```
array(5) { ["post_type"]=> string(7) "product" ["posts_per_page"]=> string(2) "20" ["post__in"]=> array(14) { [0]=> int(12695) [1]=> int(12991) [2]=> int(12999) [3]=> int(12566) [4]=> int(12568) [5]=> int(13049) [6]=> int(12570) [7]=> int(12619) [8]=> int(12589) [9]=> int(13085) [10]=> int(12925) [11]=> int(13047) [12]=> int(13081) [13]=> int(12328) } ["orderby"]=> string(8) "post__in" ["order"]=> string(3) "ASC" }
```

This kind of hack is not very elegant, but this is the best I've found.
BTW, I also tried the following in functions.php file, but it doesn't work as expected :

```
// ORDER BY
add_filter( 'wt_related_products_orderby', 'filter_woocommerce_wt_related_orderby', 10, 1 );
function filter_woocommerce_wt_related_orderby( $orderby ){
    return "post__in";
}
// ORDER
add_filter( 'wt_related_products_order', 'filter_woocommerce_wt_related_order', 10, 1 );
function filter_woocommerce_wt_related_order($order){
    return 'ASC'; 
}
```